# how can i set If admin is logged in then only they can see he is admin on index

Tags: laravel, admin, laravel-5

i have admin middleware and its working only on route

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class admin
{
    /** 
* Handle an incoming request.
     * this is only for admin
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!Auth::guest() && Auth::user()->admin) {

        return $next($request);
    }
     return redirect('/');
}
}
```

how to i show like 
`@if (Auth::user())` 
than user see name and when admin is logged in than admin will see hello admin
 
what i type for admin
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you have a column role in user table:

```
@if(Auth::user()->role == 'admin')
   <span>Hello{{Auth::user()->name}}</span>
     or 
    <span>Hello admin</span>
```

@endif

If you don't have the column role put the condition in the if statement that defines user is a admin

Comment: I think it's `Auth::user()->admin`